# When I modify a value in a json of nested dicts it is removing other dicts

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to figure out how to modify a value in a json file. I have simplified it to a dict of two dictionaries. I can modify the value in the json file, but the resulting json file is no longer a dict of dictionaries, just the one dictionary that contains the value which I have modified. Any ideas how I can fix this?

**original json file**

```
{
    "test_settings":
        {
            "rigID":"r1",
            "test":"blank"
        },
    "temperature_settings":
        {
            "temperature_start":"40.1",
            "temperature_stop":"blank",
            "temperature_step":"blank"
        }
}
```

**my code**

```
import json

def modify_json_file(json_file):
    with open(json_file, "r") as input_json:
        json_data = json.load(input_json)
        print("type of data: ", type(json_data))
        for k,v in json_data.items():
            print(k,v)
        print('\n'*2)
        temperature_settings = json_data["temperature_settings"]
        print("type of temperature_settings: ", type(temperature_settings))
        print(temperature_settings["temperature_start"])
    temperature_settings["temperature_start"] = 99.9
    with open(json_file, "w") as input_json:
        json_data = json.dump(temperature_settings, input_json)


print('\n'*25)
modify_json_file("file6.json")
```

**dict now**

```
{"temperature_start": 99.9, "temperature_stop": "blank", "temperature_step": "blank"}
```

**Desired result**

```
{
    "test_settings":
        {
            "rigID":"r1",
            "test":"blank"
        },
    "temperature_settings":
        {
            "temperature_start":"99.9",
            "temperature_stop":"blank",
            "temperature_step":"blank"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you only write back `temperature_settings` so you only get that... Just use:

```
with open(json_file, "w") as input_json:
    json.dump(json_data, input_json)
```

to have the expected result.

Comment: Hi Serge, that preserves the other dicts but is changing the json format (I don't know if that is normal or not). {"test_settings": {"rigID": "r1", "test": "blank"}, "temperature_settings": {"temperature_start": 99.9, "temperature_stop": "blank", "temperature_step": "blank"}}

Comment: This preserved the formatting: json_data = json.dump(json_data, input_json, indent = 4)

Answer (score 1):

Set the value of json_data before the write.

```
    with open(json_file, "w") as input_json:
        json_data["temperature_settings"]=temperature_settings        
        json.dump(json_data, input_json)
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following

````
def modify_json_file(json_file):
    with open(json_file, "r") as input_json:
        json_data = json.load(input_json)
        print("type of data: ", type(json_data))
        for k, v in json_data.items():
            print(k, v)
        print('\n'*2)
        temperature_settings = json_data["temperature_settings"]
        print("type of temperature_settings: ", type(temperature_settings))
        print(temperature_settings["temperature_start"])
        test_settings = json_data["test_settings"]
    temperature_settings["temperature_start"] = 99.9
    new_settings = []
    new_settings.append(test_settings)
    new_settings.append(temperature_settings)
    with open(json_file, "w") as input_json:
        json_data = json.dump(new_settings, input_json)


print('\n'*25)
modify_json_file("file6.json")```
````